# Log4net Issue inside wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, log4net

I'm using log4net in my application, it works fine every where.

I've used it in body of my WCF methods to log interactions between client and service.
when ever a WCF client calls any of the methods, an exception occurs internally inside log4net saying that is can not retrieve stack information;

This is my wcf:

```
 [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single, ConcurrencyMode =  ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
    public class MyWcfService : IMyWcfService

      {
        private static readonly ILog logger = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyWcfService));
        private static readonly object lockObject = new object();
...
...
...//other code are remove for simplicity


     public void Disconnect()
        {
            logger.DebugFormat(WcfMessages.MethodCalled, "Disconnect");

            lock (lockObject)
            {
                try
                {
                    {
                        client = null;
                        logger.Info(string.Format(WcfMessages.ClientDisconnected));
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception exception)
                {
                    logger.Error(string.Format(WcfMessages.ClientDisconnectException), exception);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Here is log4net's console appender output:

[image]

Log4Net Cofnig:

```
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger  %method  %-4line - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>
```

why i see the exception? how i can solve it?
Thanks.

Comment: You know WCF has it's own logging framework to do this? See WCF Tracing

Comment: @hugh: thanks for useful comment, but i want to use single logging framework for my application

Comment: Could be https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4NET-393 ?

Comment: If you remove the `%method` and `%line` from the conversion pattern do you still get the exceptions? Both of these try to use stack information in log4net.

Comment: I've removed them and still getting the exception! sorry for late reply